# Mechanize using ruby open up new page

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using this code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html')
form = agent.page.forms[0]
print agent.page.forms[0].fields
# in this i get filed as lccp_pnrno1
agent.page.forms[0]["lccp_pnrno1"] = "4150702245"
button = form.button_with(:value => "Get Status")
agent.submit(form, button)
pp pages
```

Ideally , The above code should first enter 10 digit no. , click on get status button , it should give a new page so new page is needed which gives information ,But my output is the first page only .So i have two doubts here:

1) how to check if the form is submitted or not.

2)Second how to print next page after submitting form as the pp page is printing last page only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
pp page
```

`page` is still referring to the original page that was assigned to it in

```
page = agent.get('http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html')
```

You need to update `page` after submitting the form:

```
page = agent.submit(form, button)
pp page
```

Note that page is being assigned the value (page) returned by the form submission.

Comment: Hey Thanks , it works just one more thing there are  6 fields which come into resulting page but script output contain 3 fields . How i can take rest fields also.

Comment: or if you could try i need This output only not whole page 1)Train no    2)Train name 3) Boarding Date 4)Booking Status 5)To                      u can find this field on new page .. i am new to ruby and will appreciate if you can help.

Comment: You will need to scrape the data from the page - see the last section of the mechanize guide (http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html). This means you will need to learn css-selectors and/or xpath. As an example, you can get the train number with `puts page.at('table.table_border').search('.//tr[3]/td[1]').text`.

Comment: Thanks of your reply , Initially when if i am printing whole page i am not getting few field information, so  will i able to get them using css selectors?

Comment: When you do `pp page`, mechanize only shows you information that it thinks is useful. If you want to see the actual html of the page, you should do `puts page.body`. The css selectors are used to help you parse the page's html and get the specific content you want.

Comment: I used tr[3]/td[3] for date-it worked and table[4]/tr[2]/td[2] for booking status but didn't get any output. i think my selector is okey as from the source code.

Comment: If you output `table[4]`, you will see that it is not the one you want. Try `table[@id="center_table"]/tr[2]/td[2]` instead.

Comment: hey this is also "puts pages.at('table.table_border').search('.//table[@id="center_table"]/tr[2]/td[2]').text" not giving any output or do i have typed something wrong here.

Comment: The code you tried says to find the table with id "center table" within the table with class "table_border". If you look at the page's html, you can see that they are sibling tables not within each other. You need to do `puts pages.at('.//table[@id="center_table"]/tr[2]/td[2]'‌​).text

Comment: Other than `pages` should be `page`, it should work. Try typing it out rather than copying/pasting. It's odd, but if I type it, it works. If I copy it, I get an exception. There is something wrong with copying the ending bracket.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27992/discussion-between-deepender-singla-and-justin-ko)